# Scraping HTML to object then AutoMapper to model

Tags: c#

I am pretty sure this process I have hashed out has many deficiencies so feel free to point out anything you see along the way.

I have an incoming HTML email that I need to scrape a lot of the information out of. I have this information going into a really simple List but then I would like to map it into a specific model which I can then work with.

The HTML email looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Name: </td>
    <td>Larry Smith</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email: </td>
    <td>larry@cucumber.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone: </td>
    <td>(101)123-4567 (Mobile)</td>
</tr>
```

I use HTMLAgilityPack to parse it into this object:

```
public class RawData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thus the object after parsing looks like this

[image]

My model is very similar EXCEPT that the properties are actually named not generic:

```
public class FullModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
     ...etc....
 }
```

So now we get to the crux of the problem...Trying to build a map with AutoMapper to line everything up.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RawData, FullData>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.FullName,
  opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

but of course....there are about 80 properties in the RawData object that are fields....and RawData is a List to boot.

Should I abandon my RawData object and mapping and instead in the email scrape parsing method find the FullData property that it belongs to and populate it?

Other ideas and input welcome

Thank You

Comment: Just to understand... `IEnumerable<RawData>` to `FullModel` (You show only `RawData` to `Model` but you'd miss out on a lot of different values...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* I understand this, and am hoping the code you have is just one method you'd tried (but obviously wasn't working as expected). With that said:

From my perspective, this looks like you want to [create a custom ValueResolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) that would find the appropriate "key" for the property. Something like:

```
class RawDataNameResolver : ValueResolver<IEnumerable<RawData>, String>
{
    private String _name;

    public RawDataNameResolver(String name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    protected override String ResolveCore(IEnumerable<RawData> source)
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            var match = source.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == _name);
            if (match != null)
            {
                return match.Value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

That keeps it pretty generic so you can re-use it in your mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<RawData>, FullModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Email, m => m.ResolveUsing(new RawDataNameResolver("Email: ")))
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, m => m.ResolveUsing(new RawDataNameResolver("Name: ")))
    .ForMember(d => d.PhoneNumber, m => m.ResolveUsing(new RawDataNameResolver("Phone: ")));
```

(Note how I'm passing the "Name" value in so e can perform a compare and receive back the "Value").

This would provide:

```
var rawData = new[]{ // pretend this just read an email ;-)
  new RawData { Name = "Name: ", Value = "Larry Smith" },
  new RawData { Name = "Email: ", Value = "larry@cucumber.com" },
  new RawData { Name = "Phone: ", Value = "(101)123-4567 (Mobile)" }
}
var fullModel = Mapper.Map<FullModel>(rawData);
```

Which results in:

```
new FullModel {
  Email = "larry@cucumber.com",
  Name = "Larry Smith",           // Yes, I've combined them!
  PhoneNumber = "(101)123-4567 (Mobile)
};
```

Now, if you want the first name, last name you could modify the `ValueResolver` bit more so you can perform some post-processing. Maybe something like:

```
class RawDataNameResolver : ValueResolver<IEnumerable<RawData>, String>
{
    private String _name;
    private Func<String, String> _postProcessor;

    public RawDataNameResolver(String name, Func<String, String> postProcessor = null)
    {
        _name = name;
        _postProcessor = postProcessor;
    }

    protected override String ResolveCore(IEnumerable<RawData> source)
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            var match = source.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == _name);
            if (match != null)
            {
                return _postProcessor != null ? _postProcessor(match.Value) : match.Value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Note I've added a post-processor so we can perform a manipulation on the value once we have it)

This changes our mapping procedure (but only slightly):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<RawData>, FullModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Email, m => m.ResolveUsing(new RawDataNameResolver("Email: ")))
    .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, m => m.ResolveUsing(new RawDataNameResolver("Name: ", x => x.Split()[0])))
    .ForMember(d => d.LastName, m => m.ResolveUsing(new RawDataNameResolver("Name: ", x => x.Split()[1])))
    .ForMember(d => d.PhoneNumber, m => m.ResolveUsing(new RawDataNameResolver("Phone: ")));
```

Which now results in:

```
new FullModel {
  Email = "larry@cucumber.com",
  FirstName = "Larry",
  LastName = "Smith",
  PhoneNumber = "(101)123-4567 (Mobile)
};
```

The same could be applied to parsing the PhoneNumber (remove `(mobile)` or just normalize it). Also, keep in mind this isn't "production ready". I would strongly suggest you don't just use `.Split()[0]` and actually break that out into something more bullet-proof (as with other places I didn't perform checks).

Comment: This was perfect. Don't know how to give you more points but would if I could. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help!